# Angular spectator testing: target component-level service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-test, angular-unit-test, angular-spectator

In my Angular app I have a [service which is provided at a component level](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  providers: [MyService],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { ... }
```

I'm using [spectator](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator/) in my Angular tests and I'm trying to test the component providing the service in the following way:

```js
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: MyComponent,
  providers: [
    // ... other services ...
    mockProvider(MyService),
  ],
  // ...
});

// ...

const spectator = createComponent();

const myService = spectator.inject(MyService);
```

But whenever I try to mock stuff on `myService` it does not work: it seems that it is getting a global instance of `MyService` instead of the component-level instance of `MyService`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important steps to take when dealing with component-level provided services in testing.

#### 1) Provide them at component-level in the test

Replace:

```js
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: MyComponent,
  providers: [
    // ... other services ...
    mockProvider(MyService),
  ],
  // ...
});

// ...

const spectator = createComponent();
```

With:

```js
const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: MyComponent,
  providers: [
    // ... other services ...
  ],
  // ...
});

// ...

const spectator = createComponent({
  mockProvider(MyService),
});
```

Note that the provider is no longer specified in the `createComponentFactory` but in `createComponent` instead.

#### 2) Get them from the component injector instead of the global one

The `spectator.inject()` method takes an optional second parameter called `fromComponentInjector` (that is `boolean`).

Replace:

```js
const myService = spectator.inject(MyService);
```

With:

```js
const myService = spectator.inject(MyService, true);
```